# Calculate Total time from array in php if total time greater than 24 hours

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I want to get the sum of the time in array. There are a lot of questions asked before related this question. Only problem this solution work the only sum is less than 24 hours. After 24 hours it will start at 00:00:00. How do I get more than 24 hours as total?

```
<?php
$total = [
'00:02:55',
'00:07:56',
'01:03:32',
'15:13:34',
'02:13:44',
'03:08:53',
'13:13:54'
 ];

$sum = strtotime('00:00:00');
$sum2=0;
foreach ($total as $v){
  $sum1=strtotime($v)-$sum;
  $sum2 = $sum2+$sum1;
}
$sum3=$sum+$sum2;
echo date("H:i:s",$sum3);
?>
```

RESULT

```
11:04:28
```

Expected result

```
35:04:28
```

[DEMO LINK](https://3v4l.org/QDiVc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
<?php

function explode_time($time) { //explode time and convert into seconds
        $time = explode(':', $time);
        $time = $time[0] * 3600 + $time[1] * 60;
        return $time;
}

function second_to_hhmm($time) { //convert seconds to hh:mm
        $hour = floor($time / 3600);
        $minute = strval(floor(($time % 3600) / 60));
        if ($minute == 0) {
            $minute = "00";
        } else {
            $minute = $minute;
        }
        $time = $hour . ":" . $minute;
        return $time;
}

$time = 0;
$time_arr =  [
'00:02:55',
'00:07:56',
'01:03:32',
'15:13:34',
'02:13:44',
'03:08:53',
'13:13:54'
 ];
 foreach ($time_arr as $time_val) {
    $time +=explode_time($time_val); // this fucntion will convert all hh:mm to seconds
}

echo second_to_hhmm($time);
?>
```

Comment: this is correct some extend. i want to get the second also

Comment: that is coming time to time not is every time

Answer (score 1):

With the external DateTime Extension [dt](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt) you can add all times to a date.
With DateTime::diff you get the result:

```
$dt = dt::create("2000-1-1");  //fix Date
$dtsum = clone $dt;
foreach($total as $time){
  $dtsum->addTime($time);
}
$diff = $dt->diff($dtsum);

printf('%d:%02d:%02d',$diff->days * 24 + $diff->h,$diff->i,$diff->s);
```

Output:
35:04:28

**Update**
Without a DateTime-Extension:

```
$dt = date_create("2000-1-1");  //fix Date
$dtsum = clone $dt;
foreach($total as $time){
  $timeArr = explode(":",$time);
  $secondsAdd = $timeArr[0] * 3600 + $timeArr[1] * 60 +$timeArr[2];
  $dtsum->modify($secondsAdd." Seconds");
}
$diff = $dt->diff($dtsum);

printf('%d:%02d:%02d',$diff->days * 24 + $diff->h,$diff->i,$diff->s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you are doing: using time to make computations ignoring date part.
Maybe considering things in another way : 1 hour = 60 seconds * 60 minutes. So convert all you iterations as seconds, do the sum at the end and write time you need yourself.

Or, or you will use some greater things from [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

```
<?php

$january = new DateTime('2010-01-01');
$february = new DateTime('2010-02-01');
$interval = $february->diff($january);

// %a will output the total number of days.
echo $interval->format('%a total days')."\n";

// While %d will only output the number of days not already covered by the
// month.
echo $interval->format('%m month, %d days');
```

Adapt to your needs, and I am sure it will work well.

Comment: bro .actual i want calculate the total number of working hours related each employee

Comment: Making a little change is so hard ? `%d days %H hours` instead of `%m month, % days`. And convert the datetime as hours. mktime() will help you.
You have to do `24* nbOfDays + HoursOfTheCurrentDay`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would completely avoid touching any date functions because you're not working with dates. You could do something like:

```
// Input data
$data = [
    '00:02:55',
    '00:07:56',
    '01:03:32',
    '15:13:34',
    '02:13:44',
    '03:08:53',
    '13:13:54'
];    

// Total to hold the amount of seconds
$total = 0;

// Loop the data items
foreach($data as $item):
    $temp = explode(":", $item); // Explode by the seperator :
    $total+= (int) $temp[0] * 3600; // Convert the hours to seconds and add to our total
    $total+= (int) $temp[1] * 60;  // Convert the minutes to seconds and add to our total
    $total+= (int) $temp[2]; // Add the seconds to our total
endforeach;

// Format the seconds back into HH:MM:SS
$formatted = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($total / 3600),($total / 60 % 60), $total % 60);

echo $formatted; // Outputs 35:04:28
```

So we loop the items in the input array and [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string by the : to get an array containing hours, minutes and seconds in indexes 0, 1, and 2.

We then convert each of those values to seconds and add to our total. Once we're done, we format back into `HH:MM:SS` format